# Removing redirection chain with single redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My website was migrated from `http://` to `https://` two years back and we applied standard redirection in *.htaccess* file. This rule is causing all requests starting with `http://` to automatically converted to `https://`.

Now, there are old pages like: http://www.example.com/product1.php (A) and which were later changed to http://www.example.com/product1/.

Now because of the .htaccess rule, the URL (A) automatically switches to https://www.example.com/product1.php. To fix this I have applied one more redirection rule:

https://www.example.com/product1.php to https://www.example.com/product1/

This is working fine, but there is a redirect chain:
http://www.example.com/product1.php (A)  --> https://www.example.com/product1.php  (B) --> https://www.example.com/product1/ (C).

Can I get rid of this redirection chain and have some mechanism so that (A) can directly re-direct to (C).

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide your current .htaccess rules

Comment: what module are you using to implement the redirection?

Comment: @karthikeayan - I am using wordpress Quick redirect option.

Comment: Felix Geenen - Just one rule in .htaccess. Any http:// request is converted to https:// automatically.